# Hyper-V Virtualisation Disabled in Firmware

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm on windows 8 and i've been trying to use hyper-v to set-up a virtual machine.
When I go into the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" the box to select Hyper-V platform, it is grayed out and when I hover "Hyper-V Cannot be installed: Virtualization is disabled in the firmware"
Can I enable it and how?

Comment: This is more a question for SuperUser. The hw feature can be found in your BIOS settings (often: F2) under OS security.

Answer (score 37):

Your host computer must support hardware virtualization, however, this feature is currently disabled.

**Enabling  in BIOS**

To successfully run Parallels virtual machines, you should enable hardware virtualization in BIOS of the host computer.In BIOS, the hardware virtualization feature is usually called VMX, VT, Virtualization Technology, Virtual Machine Extensions, or Vanderpool Technology. It can be often found under the "Security" or "CPU Features" screen, however, the location of this feature depends on the motherboard of the host computer. You can use these general guidelines to enable hardware virtualization:

```
Restart the physical computer and press Del to enter BIOS setup before the primary operating system boots up.
```

[image]
[image]
[image: enter link description here]
[image]

```
Select Advanced BIOS Features and press Enter:
```

After it is Enabled in Bios..
Follow these steps

**Enabling in Windows**

Hyper-V is installed in the add features section of the add or remove programs dialog. To get there we need to open a run box by pressing Win+R, now type appwiz.cpl and press enter. You could also get to the Programs and Features box through Control Panel or the Start search, but this is easy and geeky.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can now launch the Hyper-V manager from the Metro dashboard.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is actually working! I am able to install Windows 8.1 Emulators now! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

For Asus motherboard I also had to disable BIOS->Advanced->Boot->Fast Boot->Disable. Only then Windows started seeing changes in BIOS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to enable "Virtualization technology" in bios.

1. reboot your system then entered in the bios setting.
2. find the option for "Virtualization technology" then enable it.
3. save the setting and exit/reboot. Done :)

For eg. I have "Gigabyte UEFI bios" this feature is available under the "Bios feature" setting.
[hyper v enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Q9o.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to superuser: How is this different than the most pop. answer. Maybe more detail would provide a more rounded answer. If not this is a comment you will over time get the right to comment in the mean time please take a couple of minutes and read:- [help] .Answering: [answer], again welcome to superuser and please continue.Thankyou